# PHP Replace matching string with wildcard in a foreach array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach array which contains several text strings.

```
foreach ($this->arrCustomFields as $field) {
    echo ($field['lbl']->Name);
}
```

Following are the strings in above array.

```
abcdefg 
mention 
plcplc 
xxxx_Models
```

I want to match shell style wildcard + text "*Models" and replace it with "mymodels" and commit the changes in the same foreach array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP supports [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). You can use those with [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) to do the replacement:

```
$field['lbl']->Name = preg_replace("/.*Models/", "mymodels", $field['lbl']->Name);
```

Comment: Glad I could help ;) If this is not exactly what you're trying to replace (actually `*`can work different in different environments, it can match "as much as possible" (greedy) or "as little as necessary" (non-greedy), and one can search case-sensitive or -insensitive), tell us more about what should and should not match, and the regular expression used can be fitted to your needs.

Comment: by the way how can I contact you, do you do paid work?

Comment: @user2107349 Send me a mail to < johannes+stackoverflow[at]schweinlein.de >. No promises though.